# Questions regarding work with multiple imputation data in SPSS

Tags: spss, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I used the multiple imputation function integrated in SPSS (method: auto [meaning Markov Chain Monte Carlo or in case of monotonicity SPSS reverts to Monotone]; 5 imputations) and now I'm running into some problems working with my new data.

**Question 1:**
When running the analysis it seems the standard errors are smaller within the imputed data sets compared to the original data (1.4 in the original data vs. 1.23, 1.19, 1.21, 1.2, 1.21). Is that a problem at all or do I need to run some kind of analysis concerning the goodness of the imputation?

**Question 2:**
Running a binary logistic regression with the imputed data SPSS outputs six estimates of Nagelkerke's R2 (one for each data set). Do I need to somehow pool these by myself or which one do I look at here?

**Question 3** (similar to Q2):
In the multiple regression output SPSS displays standardized beta coefficients for each data set but no pooled beta coefficients. Do I need to calculate these myself or should I have standardized the variables before the analysis?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you tell us what "method: auto" does in multiple imputation? People might not have familiarity with SPSS or its imputation methods.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Method: auto means the Markov Chain Monte Carlo method where in case of monotonicity SPSS reverts to the Monotone method.
Edited for clarity.